# Changes in denjucks templates not reflected on refresh unless server is restarted

Tags: deno, oak

I am using 'deno' and 'oak'. for auto refreshing I am using 'denon' which is similar to 'nodemon' in nodejs. as a template engine, third party module, I am using -  'denjucks'. Whenever, I do any change in template code and save, server is not restarting automatically. How to solve this issue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved the issue. In denon.json file added following -

```
"watcher": {   
       "exts": ["js", "ts", "json", "html"]
}
```

This adds html file in watcher list.

Comment: Not only I answered first, but that's exactly my answer. You removed the accepted 5 days later to give it to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`exts`](https://deno.land/x/denon/#watcher) options and add `html`.

```
{
  "scripts": { /* */ },

  "watcher": {
    // The number of milliseconds after the last change.
    "interval": 350,
    // The file extensions that it will scan for.
    "exts": ["js", "ts", "json", "html"],
    // The globs that it will scan for.
    "match": ["*.*"],
    // The globs that it will not scan for.
    "skip": ["*/.git/*"],
    // Use the legacy file monitoring algorithm. (walking)
    "legacy": false
  }
}
```